# Keyboard shortcut to hide the extension of selected files in Finder

Tags: keyboard, finder, automator, automation, file-extensions

How can I set up a keyboard shortcut to hide the file extension of each selected file in Finder?

For example, if <kbd>⇧⌘E</kbd> were such a shortcut, I could conveniently press <kbd>⌘A</kbd> to select all files in the folder and then <kbd>⇧⌘E</kbd> to hide their extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Create a workflow to hide the selected files. Then assign a keyboard shortcut to the workflow.

1. Run **Automator**.
2. Create a new workflow document named **Hide File Extension** of type **Quick Action**.
3. Add a **Run AppleScript** action.
4. Set workflow receives current to **files or folders** in **Finder**. Replace the script content with:

```
    tell application "Finder"
        repeat with theFile in (selection as alias list)
            set extension hidden of theFile to true 
        end repeat
    end tell
```

5. Save the workflow.
6. Open **System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services**.
7. Assign a shortcut to **Files and Folders > Hide File Extension**, for example <kbd>⇧⌘E</kbd>.

You may need to run Hide File Extension once from Finder’s Quick Actions context menu before the keyboard shortcut will work.